# How to launch a XML and XSL file through a batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, xslt

Easy one, but cannot seem to remember how or find out where...
I need a simple batch file to be able to run my XSL and XML.

so for example i will have "Loading.bat" and inside it will locate and run the xsl and the xml from seperate folders; \folderA\example.xsl and \folderB\example.xml

can someone please provide me a really simple batch file to do this task?

Comment: it depends on your xsl processor...

Comment: Msxml dom? Default one for windows pc.

Comment: Afaik, msxml is not shipped with windows by default, so you need to download it.

Comment: The Saxon setup below seems the easiest, just need to install it if it's not present, thanks guys/girls

Comment: Saxon requires both saxon and JRE :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use saxon you can run the following:

```
java -jar /path/to/saxon.jar xmlfile xslfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about msxsl, then you should download it first. Then:

Bat file ms.bat:

```
msxsl.exe %1 %2 > %3
```

Run:

```
ms.bat folderA\example.xml \folderB\example.xsl out.file
```

p.s. But I'm not sure that this bat file is actually needed...